# sys.argv in main() but referencing global var in a previous function

Tags: python, function, global, program-entry-point

Trying to find a pythonic way to work around the UnboundLocalError. In this example file, I want to be able to import functions to another python script (so I can't declare `thisfile,flag1` before `main()`). The `string =` is just a way to show that I want to use `flag1` as a local variable.

What's a good work-around? (I'd rather not access `flag1` by indexing `sys.argv[1]`. Just my preference.)

```
def somefunction(flag1=flag1):
    string = "I just want to use the flag1 var (%(flag1)s)" % locals()
def main():
    somefunction()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    thisfile, flag1 = sys.argv
    main()

=====
OUT: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'flag1' referenced before assignment
```

UPDATE:
So, what I didn't say is what I'm actually doing in `somefunction` - there I'm creating an sbatch file with a general skeleton and filling in variables, so I'll need `flag1` to be local, and I'd rather not pass it along through a bunch of functions, or make multiple strings if possible (it looks prettier this way).

```
def somefunction():
    sometext = gettext()
    firstvar  = getfirstvar()
    string = '''!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --flags

./some_program --generic-flag 18 --used-every-time /some/path \
--needed-var %(sometext)s --first-var %(firstvar)s \
--final-flag %(flag1)s
''' % locals()

def main():
    somefunction()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    thisfile, flag1 = sys.argv
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to somehow pass the variable in. Below is one way to do it, verified to work (BSD).

```
def somefunction(flag1=""):
    string = "I just want to use the flag1 var (%s)" % flag1
    print(string)

def main(flag1=""):
    somefunction(flag1=flag1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys 
    thisfile, flag1 = sys.argv
    main(flag1)
```

Answer (score 0):

A neater way would be to access default flag1 only where it is needed

```
def somefunction(flag1=None):
    if flag1 is None:
        flag1 = sys.argv[1]
    string = "I just want to use the flag1 var (%(flag1)s)" % locals()
```

Comment: OP said he wants to import the function elsewhere, this will not work on imports.

Answer (score 0):

locals().update() seems to work well enough, and I don't have to pass along the var through a bunch of functions to where I actually use it.

Any further improvements welcomed.

```
def somefunction():
    locals().update({'thisfile':thisfile,'flag1':flag1})
    sometext = gettext()
    firstvar  = getfirstvar()
    string = '''!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --flags

./some_program --generic-flag 18 --used-every-time /some/path \
--needed-var %(sometext)s --first-var %(firstvar)s \
--script-used %(thisfile)s \
--final-flag %(flag1)s
''' % locals()

def main():
    somefunction()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    global thisfile,flag1
    thisfile, flag1 = sys.argv
    main()
```